# Get friends email address/phone number from Twitter API [Android]

Tags: android, twitter

Is it possible to get email address or phone number of user's friends using Twitter API?

Im aware i need to ask special permission to get user's email address. But how about the user's friends?

I checked [this official](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list) documentation, but cant find any email address or phone number field.

If it is really not possible, how do `Path` "invite" user's friends via Twitter API?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible to get email or phone number via Twitter API.
Maybe Path is sending invites using DM to your friends.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you mean direct message (DM)?

Comment: Yes. Direct message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get email address from twitter api

```
TWTRAPIClient *client = [TWTRAPIClient clientWithCurrentUser];
    [client requestEmailForCurrentUser:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
        if (email) {
            NSLog(@"signed in as %@", email);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }];
```